# Formatted output from pkginfo command

Tags: unix, solaris

To get a listing of the software versions installed on our Solaris 10 server, I can use the command `pkginfo -l`.  However, it returns the attributes on different rows, like this:

```
   PKGINST:  bteq1310
      NAME:  Teradata BTEQ Utility
  CATEGORY:  application
      ARCH:  Solaris9/SPARC
   VERSION:  13.10.00.04
   BASEDIR:  /opt
    VENDOR:  Teradata Corporation
    PSTAMP:  esssol00920110210172759
  INSTDATE:  Jul 01 2012 21:23
    STATUS:  completely installed
     FILES:       10 installed pathnames
                   6 shared pathnames
                   6 directories
                   4 executables
                1403 blocks used (approx)
```

Is there a command similar to `pkginfo` that will return the same information in columns instead of on separate lines?  I'm really only interested in the PKGINST, NAME, VERSION, INSTDATE, and STATUS values.

Answer (score 0):

This awk script appears to work:

```
BEGIN { FS=":  "; }
/PKGINST/ { pkg = $2; p[$2] = $2; } 
/NAME/ { n[pkg] = $2; } 
/VERSION/ { v[pkg] = $2; } 
/INSTDATE/ { i[pkg] = $2; } 
/STATUS/ { s[pkg] = $2; } 
END { for (m in p) printf ("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", m, n[m], v[m], i[m], s[m]) }
```